# Intercept all notifications - UWP

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

with new API, in windows 10 now there is the possibility to intercept all app's notification.
Unfortunately I could not find the online examples, so I wanted to ask if anyone can share how to intercept them in the right way.
A piece of code is always welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a new API for this added in the Anniversary Update, take a look at MSDN blog post explaining it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/05/26/notification-listener-documentation-windows-10/